# How to count model objects in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a student management website with Django. Now I want to count how many students are in a single grade and display the number in my website.
How can I do that?
My model:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, 
MinValueValidator

# Create your models here.
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    roll = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
           primary_key=True, editable=False)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    mother_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(validators= 
                   [MaxValueValidator(99999999999)])
    grade = models.ForeignKey('grade', on_delete=models.CASCADE )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Grade(models.Model):
    grade_name = models.IntegerField(validators= 
                 [MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(1)])
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, 
         primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.grade
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome on Stack Overflow, can you please paste your code in your message rather than in the screenshot?

Comment: Please read this - ```count()``` in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` then `count()` :

```
first_grade_students = Student.objects.filter(grade__grade_name =1).count()
```

Remember [using `count()`is more efficient than `len()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score 1):

if you what to group each grade without any filtering, by using following code it will group count of each group and returns it as a dict

```
from django.db.models import Count

Student.objects.all().order_by('id').values('grade__grade_name').annotate(count=Count('id', distinct=True))
```

if you want to filter a grade, the following code will return the number of students in elementary

```
Student.objects.filter(grade__grade_name=elementary).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `django.db.models  Count` like this :

```
from django.db.models import Count

q = Grade.objects.annotate(nb_students=Count('student'))
```

To access to the number of student in a Grade, do:

```
for grade in q:
    print(grade.nb_students)
```